# tarfile.open() does not extract into the right directory path

Tags: python, python-2.x, tarfile

I'm trying to extract all from a tar.gz file into the same Directory. The following code works to extract all, but the files are stored in the working directory instead of the path I entered as name.

```
import tarfile
zip_rw_data = r"P:\Lehmann\Test_Python_Project\RW_data.tar.gz"
tar = tarfile.open(name=zip_rw_data, mode='r')
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

How do I make sure the extracted files are saved in the directory path where I need them? I've been trying at this for ages, I really can't see why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
import tarfile
zip_rw_data = r"P:\Lehmann\Test_Python_Project\RW_data.tar.gz"
tar = tarfile.open(name=zip_rw_data, mode='r')
tar.extractall(path=r"P:\Lehmann\Test_Python_Project")
tar.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using  shutil.unpack_archive

```
def extract_all(archives, extract_path):
    for filename in archives:
        shutil.unpack_archive(filename, extract_path)
```